# embed generic media player

Tags: javascript, html, media-player

i embeded windows media player by:

```
<div>
    <object classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" id="player">
    <param name="ShowPositionControls" value="false" />
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true" />
    <param name="AutoStart" value="0" />
    </object>
</div>
```

it's works fine on "Internet Explorer" but only there,
on chrome and mazola it didn't works..

i need a media player that ables me to:

1. call play from javascript
2. call pause from javascript
3. get/set the current position from javascript
4. change the song from javascript

note: i heard about audio tag, but it's probebly not supported (yet) in most browsers people have..

Comment: Other browsers support the `<video>` and `<audio>` tags of HTML5, perhaps it is useful to you. Use them in non-IE browsers, and your code in IE.

Comment: heh, i recently made a flash media player that does all of that.

Comment: someone told me that flash audio quality is not so good, is it true?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the <embed ... /> tag required for other browsers. Check out [this page](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html) for general overview and then [this one](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html) to see how to convert PARAMs to Embed attributes.

Comment: let me get this stright, IE will read the Object tag, and the other explorers will read the EMBED tag instead?